# want to redirect http://zbc.in/example/1234/abcde to http://zbc.in/m/example/1234/abcde

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Want to redirect 'http://zbc.in/example/1234/abcde' to 'http://zbc.in/m/example/1234/abcde'. I am not getting any solution. What should i write in htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific on what rules must be honored when redirecting.

I am guessing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [L]
```

Comment: try using [301,L] at the end of the rule instead of [L]